# Cannot read property length of undefined when the value is NULL

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to read the property `notes` of my object, and my code working fine. But in some case, when the value is NULL I get this error:

> Cannot read property length of undefined

This is my code:

```
(val[i]['notes'].length > 30) ? val[i].substring(0, 30)
```

the variable val contain the current object in the for. The problem appear only then the value of `val` is:

```
NULL
```

How I can avoid this situation?

Answer (score 3):

Add more checks to your condition:

```
(val[i].hasOwnProperty('notes') && val[i]['notes'] && val[i]['notes'].length > 30) ? val[i].substring(0, 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a check to your code

```
if(val[i] !== null && val[i]!== undefined){
(val[i]['notes'].length > 30) ? val[i].substring(0, 30)
}
else{
//add a case here
}
```

You can also use

```
if(val[i]){
(val[i]['notes'].length > 30) ? val[i].substring(0, 30)
}
else { 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the rest of the code?

You have a ternary without an else. Where is your var and what is the default? I would expect

```
var notes = val && 
            val[i] && 
            val[i]['notes'] &&
            val[i]['notes'].length > 30 ? val[i]["notes"].substring(0, 30):"";
```